# How to change the direction of the force with a high resolution

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

I have a sample of 600 milligrams which is supported by a rope. So the force is in the vertical direction. Now I want to change the direction to the horizontal direction while keeping the force equal(1 microgram accuracy). The first idea would be to use bearings. But if you calculate the resolution which is caused by friction, it would correspond 0.6 milligrams accuracy while I want a resolution of 0.001 milligrams.

Do you have any ideas how to change the direction of the force while retaining a high resolution?

Kind regards

[image: Bearing used to change direction of force]
Bearing converting force to horizontal plane.

Comment: Let me get this straight - you want to take a horizontal 0.006 N force, and turn it through 90°, with less than 0.00000001 N of resistance, such that an 0.00599999N force is applied upwards? If you want an 0.006N force upwards, why not just use the bearing, and apply 0.00606N horizontally to account for your bearing friction? [Newtons used for emphasis of how ridiculously tiny 0.001 mg is]

Comment: I am able to measure these very small forces but you can imagine that this measured force depends severely on the friction calculation in the bearing. The accuracy of the setup to measure the force is not the limiting factor anymore, now the friction calculation in the bearing is. Therefore I want to find another method to turn the force.

Comment: And of course I get a kind of stick and slip behaviour which completely destroys the accuracy of the setup.

Comment: So you're trying to measure the weight of the hanging mass? Anyway, have you looked into Magnetic bearings? They still have losses when rotating, but should (in my understanding) eliminate friction/sticktion for a static application such as this.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to apply a small controlled horizontal force to something, without dangling a tiny weight on a "string" (which I guess is about the diameter of a human hair) over a pulley. You might get better advice if you tell us *what you are trying to do,* not how you failed to do it accurately enough.

Comment: As you can see in the image, I have a sample with a certain weight. Material will be removed with a plasma and I am interested in the change of weight. To measure the force the sample is attached to a beam. The beam will deflect and the deflection is measured. In vertical direction this works all fine but the problem is that gravity plays an important role. The weight of the beam will also change a little bit due to the plasma and this will also cause deflection of the beam. To prevent this I want to rotate the beam and apply the force in horizontal direction.